# How to hide crossed-out CSS lines on firebug?

Tags: css, firebug

When inspecting elements of a website usning firebug, there are always couple lines of CSS that are crossed out and not so useful. Is there a way to hide them and only leave the active CSS lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the <kbd>Style ∇</kbd> tab, click the down arrow <kbd>∇</kbd> and select <kbd>Only Show Applied Styles</kbd>